# JS correcting syntax in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, ide, sublimetext3

Im new to to Sublime Text 3. I used to use Netbeans which had a great syntax correcting system for JavaScript and PHP. So far, Sublime has great features. Its fast and beautiful, but it does not have syntax correcting errors when I create JS files. Is it a possibility to get this working? I read a bit on "SublimeLinter" but when I installed it, it seems to not work correctly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to install SublimeLinter [**for Sublime Text 3**](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/tree/sublime-text-3)?

(I don't think this package is directly available in the Package control plugin, so you have to dowload the .zip and extract it in your Sublime Text 3/Packages folder)

[Edit:][Check:](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/tree/sublime-text-3#javascript-based-linters) "If you plan to edit files that use a JavaScript-based linter (JavaScript, CSS), your system must have a JavaScript engine installed. Mac OS X comes with a preinstalled JavaScript engine called JavaScriptCore, which is used if Node.js is not installed. On Windows, you must install the JavaScript engine **Node.js**, which can be downloaded from the Node.js site."

Comment: I already have tried to install the sublimeLinter but it is not working.

Comment: I tried downloading and installing Node.js but it is still not doing anything

Comment: And it was the one specially for sublime Text 3 (because there are 2 branches) ? Otherwise, it 's works for me (obviously with node installed).

Comment: Thanks. i ended up going with Sublime Text 2, but in the end the linting feature is really bad. I decided to go back to Netbeans and install the Monokai Theme.

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Linter 3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint) is the way I've found useful so far.

- To use it, first you must install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your system.
- Then, using package manager find and install `Sublime Linter` and `Sublime Linter-jshint`, quit from `Sublime Text.`
- Type `npm install -g jshint` onto your terminal, open `Sublime Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy...well kind of ! here are the steps :

hint: before you do this remove a semicolon or something from you .js file to make sure you have an error for a file to test this with:

1. Follow this steps on the clip below:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVE3E9AvRag
2. Right click on the file and then run jshint 
   [image]
3. If you still don't see the yellow line editor then:

cd '/path/to/Sublime Text 3/Packages'
git clone https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3.git SublimeLinter

you should see this errors/yellow dot on the line with error auto-magically :

[image]