# Passing a param to an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass an parameter to an anonymous function. But Something is wrong and I cannot figure it out.

```js
function getInfo(item) {
  alert(item); //does not pass the item?
}
var param = "Param was passed successfully!";
var elementel = document.getElementById("AlretBtn");
elementel.addEventListener("click", getInfo.bind(null, param, false);
```

```html
<button id="AlretBtn">Alert Item</button>
```

What's wrong with this? How can I fix this?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis at the end of the `addEventListener` call. Check your Javascript console for the syntax error message.

Comment: Probably because the JS isn't syntactically valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intend to do, but you're not binding anything to getInfo(). In case you wanted to bind the click handler to the button element:

```
function getInfo(item){
    alert(item); //does not pass the item?
    console.log(this); // the button element instead of Window
}
var param = "Param was passed successfully!";
var elementel = document.getElementById("AlretBtn");
elementel.addEventListener("click", getInfo.bind(elementel, param, false));
```

And in case you don't need to bind the click handler to it, why bother with bind()?:

```
function getInfo(item){
    alert(item); //does not pass the item?
}
var param = "Param was passed successfully!";
var elementel = document.getElementById("AlretBtn");
elementel.addEventListener("click", function(){ getInfo(param); });
```

[without bind()](http://jsfiddle.net/luismartin/2gL1ja3w/)

Comment: Thanks Luls. Useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getInfo(item) {
  alert(item); //does not pass the item?
}
var param = "Param was passed successfully!";
var elementel = document.getElementById("AlretBtn");
elementel.addEventListener("click", getInfo.bind(null, param, false));
```

```html
<button id="AlretBtn">Alert Item</button>
```

You are missing a parenthesis. I don't know if you are using an IDE, or what is your development environment. But, try to add a javascript syntax validator, it really makes development so much faster :)

Comment: thanks @davenewton removed it. It's like a reflex :O/

Comment: you mean a bad habit ;)

Comment: ahahahahahaah yep, that sounds more accurate. @robbie

Comment: thanks cacho. :) I use sublime3 - any package suggestions?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435857/js-correcting-syntax-in-sublime-text-3) ? if you are running this in the browser, you can try firebug also, it will show you the javascript errors in the console, that could be a good start.